# How can I supply a table name at runtime using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I have to use LINQ to SQL and along with it a pure SQL classic query. And this SQL query has the Table from where my data will be generated, but I will not know this Table previously. It will be known in compile time.

So how can I make LINQ understand from what Table I want to make the query?

Answer (score 1):

Good discussion here: [Dynamic SQL table name](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6273d072-f500-4382-afb4-8eafd185794d)